# Как по нажатий остановить toast?

Tags: android

```
butCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Правильно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
}});
butStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toast.cancel();
}});
//Не получается
```

Comment: У вас пишет, что не видит `toast`? Попробуйте вынести переменную Toast toast на уровень класса полем. В методе `butCheck...` инициализируйте её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Правильно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

butCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toast.show();
}});
butStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toast.cancel();
}});
```